# Cant get Beautymail to work for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use [Beautymail](https://github.com/Snowfire/Beautymail)  for my project to send a receipt after a customer ordered something. The problem is I'm using Beautymail in a function not in a route like their Documentation states.

This is how im using it in my function:

```html
 class OrderController extends Controller {



    public function postOrder(Request $request) {

        // More stuff here, shortned for question purposes

        // Get an instance of the currently authenticated user
        $user = Auth::user();


        // Send email conformation to user that just bought a product or products.
        $beautymail = app()->make(Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
        $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) {
            $message
                ->from('example@admin.com')
                ->to($user->email, $user->username)
                ->subject('Your Receipt');
        });


        // Then return redirect back with success message
        flash()->success('Success', 'Your order was processed successfully. A receipt has been emailed to you');

        return redirect()->route('cart');

    }

}
```

And this is the error I get when I "Checkout":

[image: My error]

Is there something I have to add? I already did my composer.json file along with adding it into the Providers Array, and publishing it to assets folder like in documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
```

Note the `\` before `Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class`.

Or, at the top of your controller:

```
use Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail;
```

and in your method you can have Laravel automatically resolve it through the IoC container, like:

```
public function postOrder(Request $request, Beautymail $beautymail) 
{
    $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) {
    // etc...
}
```

**Extra info on namespaces in PHP:**

When you reference a class outside of `use`, you need to declare where the if your class is in the global namespace or not. So when you had:

```
app()->make(Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
```

without the leading `\`, PHP will assume you're looking for the requested with in the current namespace, which for you is `\App\Http\Controllers`.

By adding the leading `\` you're telling PHP that the path to your class is relative to the global namespace.

Here's more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: Yes Thank You, and yes, I forgot about the leading slash

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. It's easy to miss the small (but often important) things!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class` is missing in your Laravel project. Have you installed as it mentions on https://github.com/Snowfire/Beautymail If you have not, please do so.